# Image stack with HTML5/CSS3

Tags: html, css

I know there are many examples, but essentially without any garbage usually involved, how can one do an image stack using the new `HTML5 + CSS3` style, that is:

- only single image displayed at the time
- next image shown over the previous image after some event (e.g. a mouse-down; round-robin)

I would like to know how to do this simple thing using the new `HTML5/CSS3` style?

Comment: Do you want a slideshow of images?

Comment: I don't think this is really an HTML5 / CSS3 question if you want to use jQuery.

Comment: ^Last line says this @SpaceBeers `I would like to know how to do this simple thing using the new HTML5/CSS3 style.`

Comment: @Liquid - I saw, but 1st paragraph says "+ jQuery", plus it's tagged with jQuery.

Comment: @SpaceBeers yeah I read that but the question also states Image stack with HTML5/CSS3. So I don't know what he really wants.

Comment: @Liquid - no same here. In terms of browser usage for a production site then jQuery is safest. If it's just messing around with CSS3 then I retract my answer.

Comment: @SpaceBeers well jQuery might be the safest to do so but personally I dislike it because JS can be disabled. And I think my css3 tutorial that I found looks pretty neat and doesn't rely on javascript.
Don't like to rely on other peoples code.

Comment: @Liquid - Good point but I think you'd find a smaller number of users with JS turned off than users with full CSS3 support but that's just me. They do look interesting though.

Comment: @SpaceBeers Indeed good point. But I guess it's up to James deciding if he wants to 'write'(**copy**) a lot of code or use the JQuery.

Comment: @Liquid - Exactly. I love experimenting with CSS3, but the practical developer thinks jQuery is the sensible move for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found pretty good examples for a slideshow if that's what you are looking for without to much extra in it. One with showing a timer for the next photo and an other one that changes the background.

Both CSS3 solutions and nice step per step tutorials

[Timed slideshow (box)](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/)
[Timed slideshow (background)](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/)

I hope I didn't misinterpreted your question.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use jQuery Cycle - http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

```
<div id="shuffle" class="pics">    
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />    
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />    
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />    
</div>

$('#shuffle').cycle({
    fx:     'fade',
    delay:  -4000
});
```

I'm not sure there is an HTML5 / CSS3 method for this to be honest. It's just regular CSS as all you're doing is setting the container to the image dimensions and then setting every image to absolute positioning so they're "stacked" on top of each other. Cycle then runs through them all doing the animation.

You could use CSS3 transitions but you mentioned jQuery in your question so Cycle is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

this is the best that I have ever found

```
.stack {  position: relative; z-index: 10; }
.stack img { max-width: 180px; height: 180px; vertical-align: bottom; border: 5px solid #fff; border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
```